# How to configure EHcache for standalone Java program without using hibernate / spring interceptors?

Tags: java, ehcache

Can anyone please post an example to configure `Ehcache` for a standalone java application?

I have the following simple requiremens:

- getting data from database,
- formatting that data and
- writing to file

I am using `jdbctemplate.Query`, it is executing quickly but the retrieval from list is taking quite a while. `List` is holding large volume of data (resultset).

Can anyone suggest how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old post, but it seems to kick back regularly so....

You should follow Pascal's advice and read those samples, but here is a snip of sample code to get you started (translated from Scala, I did not fully check the syntax)

1. First, put `net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.9.0` and its dependencies in your ClassPath
2. To create a cache, it is as simple as

   ```
   CacheManager cacheMgr = CacheManager.newInstance();

   //Initialise a cache if it does not already exist
   if (cacheMgr.getCache("MyCache") == null) {
       cacheMgr.addCache("MyCache");
   }
   ```

Instantiate the CacheManager only once in your code and reuse it.

3. The behaviour of your cache is dictated by an XML configuration file called `ehcache.xml` which must be available on your classpath. You can also do it programatically. The file could look like

```xml
    <ehcache>
        <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
        <cache name="MyCache"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="120"
           timeToLiveSeconds="120"
           maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000"
           diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            >
           <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
        </cache>
    </ehcache>
```

For details on the parameters, check http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/configuration

4. Use it

   ```
   //use it
   Cache cache = cacheMgr.getCache("MyCache");

   //Store an element
   cache.put(new Element("key", mySerializableObj));

   //Retrieve an element
   Element el = cache.get("key");
   Serializable myObj = <Serializable>el.getObjectValue();
   ```

Try storing serializable objects so you can easily overflow to a storage device.

Answer (score 0):

Check *the [Code Samples and Recipes](http://ehcache.org/documentation/samples.html) chapter for more information on direct interaction with ehcache*.

> #### Recipes and Code Samples
>
> The Recipes and Code Samples page
>   contains recipes - short concise
>   examples for specific use cases - and
>   a set of code samples that will help
>   you get started with Ehcache.

They cover several use cases and provide several code samples, which is just what you're asking for.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply.I never used cache. I went through the sample code ,but i did not understand how to cache my result list in cache and get from there. Could you please explain more .

Comment: thanks for reply. I'm new to ehcache and trying to replicate the sample code. I configured ehcache.xml , and in java method i'm created  CacheManager manager = new CacheManager("src/config/ehcache.xml"); manager.addCache("here i'm trying to give resultlist "); but it's expecting string . So how do i cache my resultlist so that i can use it for writing to file. It would be great if you can give any suggestions.

Comment: @ari First, I'm really not sure to understand the problem you're trying to solve and if you're on the right path. Anyway, the API you're looking for is `cache.put(new Element("key1", "value1"))` (taken from the samples). You really need to go a bit through the documentation and the samples, they contain everything you need to get started.